# Why can't I get any performance improvements by running multiple threads in C++11?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing

I have the following test program with a simple function that finds primes which I am trying to run in multiple threads (just as an example).

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <thread>

void primefinder(void)
{
   int n = 300000;

   int i, j;
   int lastprime = 0;
   for(i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
      for(j = 2; j <= i; j++) {
           if((i % j) == 0) {
               if(i == j)
                   lastprime = i;
               else {
                   break;
               }
           }
      }
   }

   std::cout << "Prime: " << lastprime << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
   std::clock_t start;
   start = std::clock();

   std::thread t1(primefinder);
   t1.join();

   std::cout << "Time: " << (std::clock() - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000) << " ms" << std::endl;

   start = std::clock();

   std::thread t2(primefinder);
   std::thread t3(primefinder);
   t2.join();
   t3.join();

   std::cout << "Time: " << (std::clock() - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000) << " ms" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

As shown, I run the function once in 1 thread and then once in 2 different threads. I compile it with g++ using -O3 and -pthread. I am running it on Linux Mint 18. I have a Core i5-4670. I know it comes down to the OS but I would very much expect these threads to run in somewhat parallel. When I run the program, top shows 100% CPU when using 1 thread and 200% CPU when using 2 threads. Despite this the second run takes almost exactly twice as long.

The CPU is doing nothing else while running the program. Why doesn't this get executed in parallel ?

**Edit:** I know both threads are doing the exact same thing. I chose the primerfinder function simply as an example of something embarrassingly parallel  so when I run it in multiple threads it should take just as long in real time.

Comment: If you want the OS to run the threads in two cores at the same time, you will need some OS specific API calls; preferably calls that tell the OS to run on separate cores.  Otherwise, the OS is going to play round-robin with all the threads, tasks and executables in the system and your threads may not run in parallel (they may be swapped a execution points convenient to the OS).

Comment: You can try setting core explicitly using `cpu_set_t` (in linux)  and provide a low nice value.

Comment: I don't see how the multiple threads complement each other. They are calling the same exact function. It seems you are just executing the same exact thing multiple times. Perhaps you want one thread to search for primes > 200000, and the other searches for those < 200000

Comment: A few things that can prevent speedups with threads (not directly relevant to your code, just thought I'd mention them) are: 1) false sharing 2) synchronization overhead 3) scheduling overhead 4) thread startup time overhead. Especially if the work done in parallel is not very great.

Comment: @thomas That is hogwash

Comment: @Yakk:  Please clarify why my answer is *hogwash*.

Comment: @thomas because it contains next to no truth?  I am aware of zero modern OSes that behave in the way you describe.  So hogwash, as in nonsense, as in harmfully useless statements.  If it was an answer instead of a comment, I would downvote.  (Note that if even if there are corner cases where you find an OS that single threads each process by default (maybe some embedded system?), it remains an over-broad claim).  Or, in short, in what way is it *not* hogwash?

Comment: @Yakk he isn't completely wrong. Just because you create a thread does not mean that it will be run on another core (even assuming other cores exist).  If you want a 100% promise of running on another core, you do need an OS specific API to assure it.  If the OS decided to put the two threads on the same core they would be executed round robin.  SO his answer is not hogwash, although it is OS specific.  For example its preferable for an OS to put multiple IO bound threads of a process on the same core, as they can be switched between without invalidating some of the cache.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using std::clock to time a parallel program in c++ is very deceptive.  There are two types of time that we care about when timing a program: wall time and cpu time.  Wall time is what we are all used to (think clock on a wall).  Cpu time is essentially how many cpu cycles your program used.  std::clock returns cpu time (this is why you are dividing by CLOCKS_PER_SEC) and cpu time is only equal to wall time when there is one thread of execution.  If a program can be run 100% in parallel (like your's), then cpu time = (number of threads)*(wall time).  So seeing almost exactly twice as long is exactly what you would expect.

For measuring wall time (which is what you want to do), I don't know of a way to do that using the STL.  You can measure it using OpenMP or Boost.

[omp_get_wtime()](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/omp_005fget_005fwtime.html)

[Boost Timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html)

Since you are on linux, the version of g++ that you are using more than likely has openmp support built in.

```
#include <omp.h>

const double startTime = omp_get_wtime();
..... //Work goes here

const double time = omp_get_wtime() - startTime;
```

You will have to compile with -fopenmp

**EDIT:**

As johnbakers pointed out, the chrono library does have a [wall clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock)

```
#include <chrono>

auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
.... //Do some work

auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
std::cout << "Time: " << diff.count() << "(s)" << std::end;
```

Output of that vs. boost timer:

```
Boost: 121.685972s wall, 724.940000s user + 67.660000s system = 792.600000s CPU  (651.3%)
Chrono: 121.683(s)
```

Comment: _"cpu time is only equal to wall time when there is one thread of execution"_ Not even that. Consider other processes on the system, consider system calls...

Comment: Were you able to confirm that using `clock` is the main issue here and with your measuring setup you do not observe the same slowness ?

Comment: what about all the utils in std::chrono ?

Comment: @johnbakers: E said the STL, not the C++ standard library.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit hm? STL is the old name for the C++ standard library

Comment: @johnbakers: No, STL is the precursor to the C++ standard library. Some of the Standard Library was based on the STL, but much of it wasn't, including `std::string`, the `std` namespace itself, and almost _all_ features added after C++03... including chrono (which instead came from Boost).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit but the OP is asking about C++11 and therefore about the C++ standard library. the OP makes no mention of the STL

Comment: @johnbakers: The OP didn't, but you seemed to imply that this answerer claimed there was no standard solution. Whereas, instead, and I directly quote from this answer: _"I don't know of a way to do that using the STL"_. Of course, suggesting a standard solution like `std::chrono` over OpenMP or Boost is a great idea, and we thank you for that. :)

Comment: This answer is not using the same definition of STL that you are using.

Comment: @johnbakers: How do you know? Until stated otherwise, I will assume that the answer uses the correct meaning of "STL" rather than some made-up nonsense. You should do the same.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it is much more likely that the answer is using the common term STL as analogous to the standard library and not to the old original STL you refer to, as that is more likely in the context of _c++11_ and, in general, most professional c++ devs I know still use the phrase STL to refer to the _current_ standard library, even if this is not an accurate use of the term.

Comment: @johnbakers: I would be happy to review the data and statistical analysis model that you have used to arrive at this conclusion.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit a simple search for site:ycombinator.com "stl" will show how the term is most often used, regardless of its accuracy

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. I use STL to refer to the current c++ library, old habits die hard.

Comment: don't worry, you and about 90% of all c++ developers. common mistake, any reasonable person would know what you meant.

Comment: @johnbakers: Extremely scientific analysis. Good work.

Comment: @johnbakers: Oh, why do you feel the need to make personal insults to back your point now? How disappointing. Why couldn't you have just stuck to the objective discussion at hand? Sigh.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit indeed, your permanent fixation on how "stl" is used gets in the way of meaningful discussions, and that _is_ disappointing.

Comment: @johnbakers: No, it doesn't "get in the way": it allows for _unambiguous_ and _clear_ communication. As you grow in age and experience, you will no doubt learn the value of _precision_. While I encourage you to try to avoid dismissing opposing views as "fixation" or "anality", in the future, I wish you luck in your continued learning endeavours. I wish the same luck to the poor souls sucked into this youth religion of lazy imprecision who have come along to support you with comment upvotes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i place strong liklihood I am much older than you, and a great lesson you can look forward to is the useful balance to learn between understanding the intent and the letter of an exchange

Comment: @johnbakers: I'm sorry that you felt the need to transform what could have been an informative and constructive exchange into a bashing contest. I shan't be responding again.

Comment: Ignoring the STL discussion I think it is worth mentioning `<chrono>` over other libs.

Comment: Riveting reading, this thread. But to chime in here, I work at a prop trading firm and we use C++ for nearly the whole business. I'm surrounded by geniuses with decades of experience, and one of them recently had his proposal for C++17 accepted, a utility function in the `std` namespace. And even he sometimes uses the term "STL" and no one is misunderstanding him, probably because we are too busy getting actual work done. If someone made a big deal about the history lesson of SGI where I'd work, it would not reflect well on him. Let's move on.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys - my problem was indeed that i was measuing CPU time instead of real time. I guess I failed at RTFM'ing for std::clock. When I switched to chrono (and did some verification) I get the expected result.

Comment: wouldn't `steady_clock` be a better choice than `system_clock`?

Answer (score 2):

There's a pretty basic problem in your design, which explains why you don't see any benefits from threads.

When you have a search problem like this and you want to speed it up with parallelization, the idea is usually to use **divide and conquer**. You need to somehow divy up the work so that e.g. the first thread will do the first half of the work, and the second thread will do the second half of the work.

In your code, both threads call exactly the same function and they don't communicate -- they each duplicate the other guy's work!

In some problems it's really easy to divy up the work. For instance, if you were working on a [SAT solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem), one way to divide the work between two threads would be to choose a variable `x_1`, and say, the first thread will assume `x_1 = true` and check if the formula is satisfiable, and the second thread will assume `x_1 = false` and check if the formula is satisfiable. Then when they are both joined you will know if overall the formula is satisfiable, and there are no mutexes or interthread communication needed.

In your primes problem it's a bit more complicated. You could try to do something like, the first thread only considers candidates ending in `1, 3, 5` and the second thread considers candidates ending in `7, 9`. For best performance though, you probably want to use something like "[Eratosthenes' Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)" and I think that would be a little harder to parallelize. (You could maybe use an array of atomics?)

Comment: I'm afraid you missed my point with the primerfinder function simply being an example. My real problem was that executing the work twice should not take twice as long since it can be parallelized. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

There are many *possible* reasons why the code is not in parallel.

In days of old, operating systems would run pieces of executables in a round-robin or priority method.  So one thread of execution could run for a couple of milliseconds, then swapped out with another thread of execution.  This would give the *appearance* that threads of execution are run in parallel.

The swapping out of threads of execution would also occur when one thread waits on a resource and the resource is not available.

In modern computers, with multiple processors or cores, the technique is still the same.  The OS has another processor it can delegate tasks to.  Core time is precious.  The OS is unlikely to stop all the running tasks on multiple cores so your threads can execute in parallel.  This probably means that the OS would have to wait for one processor to finish so your threads can be executed at the same time.  Most likely ain't going to happen.

However, many OS have attributes that you can set up to tell them to give your threads exclusive access to one or more cores.  Since this is not a standard C++ functionality and OSes are not all the same, you'll have to look up the API or any compiler specific support.

**Edit 1: Interrupts and other tasks**
Keep in mind that your platform is not running your programs exclusively.  Other tasks are lurking and may be executing while your program is running.  Some examples include: virus checkers, things pinging the internet, and music players (at least on my machine).

These applications and interrupts may cause the OS to play round-robin with your threads on the same processor and not in parallel.  Once scenario would be to have the music player on one processor why your program is running on another.

Comment: Thomas Matthews you couldn't be more correct. I am running Windows 10, with a browser that has many tabs open. I also have VSCode up in several windows. When I open Task Manager, it shows I have 8500 threads running in 404 processes! All of that has to be juggled between 24 cores! Absolutely!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`std::chrono` namespace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono). It offers many C++11 utilities for measuring time that are superior to every suggestion here thus far.

For example, you can [cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast) a clock reading to wall time.

Timing programming code is not trivial, but these tools do make it easier to explore along these lines.